# Why does the type conversion from Class[String] to Class[Any] compile successfully?

Tags: scala, generics

Why does the type conversion from Class[String] to Class[Any] compile successfully ?

```
object Test extends App {
  var anyClass: Class[Any]    = classOf[Any]
  val strClass: Class[String] = classOf[String]

  /* The following codes compile error: Expression of type Class[String] doesn't conform to expected type Class[Any]. */
  //oClass = sClass

  /* The following codes compile and run successfully. */
  val str2anyClass = strClass.asInstanceOf[Class[AnyRef]]

  println(str2anyClass.toString) // Output: class java.lang.String

}
```

Comment: Funny,  `println(List("a", "b").asInstanceOf[List[Int]])` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the type conversion from Class[String] to Class[Any] compile
>   successfully ?

Because `Class[A]` is invariant in `A`, and according to Scala specification, your code is invalid.

When you explicitly cast with `asInstanceOf`, all bets are off and you tell the compiler that you know what you're doing and that it should trust you.

Comment: Thanks for rapid reply. Because Class[String] doesn't conform to Class[Any]，asInstanceOf should throw a RuntimeException, but it didn't, why ?

Comment: @joymufeng Because `Class[String]` can be viewed as `Class[AnyRef]`, as `String <: AnyRef`. Don't forget the generic type parameters are erased.

Comment: Thanks very much! One more question. Can we do it in java? I find `(Class<Object>)strClass` doesn't compile in java.

Comment: @joymufeng `Class<Object> objClass = (Class<Object>)(Object)String.class;` Why would you want to do this at all?

Comment: I'm writing codes like this `value.getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[JValue]]`, `value` could be `JObject` or `JArray` which is subclass of `JValue`. I just want to know how it works. And now it's clear. Thanks for help.

Comment: Funny,  `println(List("a", "b").asInstanceOf[List[Int]])` also works.

Comment: @joymufeng No, it doesn't. Try doing any operation on the casted result and you'll get a runtime exception (again, type erasure). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089390/why-asinstanceof-doesnt-throw-a-classcastexception

Comment: Get it. Thanks again!